# Create a search bar function to filter Graphql data

Tags: next.js, graphql, uisearchbar

I have been working on a project using Nextjs that fetches data from Graphql api I have defined categories and posts models that work well when filtering by Category. I want to implement an input search bar function but i do not know how to associate it with the Graphql api I have searched on how to do it using Apollo client but it seems there is not much info on this specific subject. Here is my search component so far

```
export function Search(){

    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(CATEGORIES_QUERY);

    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;
  
    const categories = data.categories;
  
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
  
    const handleSearch = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      onSearch(searchText); // Notify the parent component about the search
    };


    return (
        <div className="flex items-center"> 
        <form className='flex space-x-1'>
         <input 
                     type="text"
                     className="block w-full px-4 py-2 text-purple-700 bg-white border rounded-full focus:border-purple-400 focus:ring-purple-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-opacity-40"
                     placeholder="Search..."  
                    onChange={(e) => setSearchText(e.target.value)}
                     />
         <button 
         className="px-4 text-white bg-purple-600 rounded-full"
         onClick={handleSearch}
         >
                     <svg
                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                         className="w-5 h-5"
                         fill="none"
                         viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                         stroke="currentColor"
                         strokeWidth={2}
                     >
                         <path
                             strokeLinecap="round"
                             strokeLinejoin="round"
                             d="M21 21l-6-6m2-5a7 7 0 11-14 0 7 7 0 0114 0z"
                         />
                     </svg>
                 </button>
 
        </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I do not know if i am in the right track, I am a little lost here. Any ideas on how to do it or any other technologies that I should use?